# How to check whether Audit fields are editable?

Tags: system-fields

Is there any way to check whether we have a permission to change audit fields in salesforce . 
Is salesforce provide any user interface to show information which audit fields are editable in which objects. I am new to the Org, which i am working in . I think ,earlier it was requested to make audit fields editable . I want to know what are those fields.

Answer (score 2):

**Check whether you have permission to set audit fields or not:**

As mentioned above, there must be two permissions:
(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enable-Create-Audit-Fields&language=en_US&type=1)

1. Setup -> Customize -> User Interface -> Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions m**ust be selected.** AND
2. Your user must have permission "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" AND "Update Records with Inactive Owners" either by Profile or Permission set --> System Permissions.

**User interface to show information which audit fields are editable in which objects.**

*There is no user interface in salesforce but there is help article that lists
fields and Object where we can set audit fields.*
(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Considerations-before-having-Create-Audit-Fields-enabled&language=en_US&type=1)

These fields are permitted additional access through the activation of this feature across the below noted objects:

- CreatedByID
- CreatedDate
- LastModifiedbyID
- Last ModifiedDate

Additionally, fields from the Lead object related to conversion can also be defined on insert:

- ConvertedDate
- ConvertedAccountId
- ConvertedContactId
- ConvertedOpportunityId

The objects that you can set these fields on are:

- Account
- CampaignMember
- Case
- CaseComment
- Contact
- Content Version
- Contracts - as of Spring '15
- FeedComment
- FeedItem
- Idea
- IdeaComment
- Lead
- Opportunity
- Vote
- Work Order
- Task and Events
- **All Custom Objects**
- Attachments

Comment: This is changing the audit field on CREATE what about when the field is already created can it be UPDATED?

Comment: @compski, Salesforce don't have the option to update created date for existing records. I tried with Data loader and it's not showing created date to map to date updates .

Comment: Cheers @KSL I have also written a question asking this

Comment: Audit field can not be updated! it can be provided while insertion only.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below link where you can get the inforamtion related to your post.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Updating-Audit-Fields/td-p/313137

Comment: Your link is already broken. Next time can you quote a snippet of the answer from the broken link?

Answer (score 1):

For a System Administrator to enable the feature they can follow the click-path below:
Setup -> Customize -> User Interface -> Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions

After enabling this organization wide permission, you need to grant to the user the profile permissions:
Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation - in order to allow the user to Set audit fields, such as **Created By and Last Modified By, Created Date and Last Modified Date**, when you create a record (API only i.e Importing Tools) through Data Loader.
Update Records with Inactive Owners - in order to allow the user to Update owner and sharing-based fields on records with inactive owners.

Salesforce Support can turn on the Create Audit Fields feature for your organization in the event it's not correctly enabled.

While this feature is generally low risk, we recommend taking the time to review as much documentation as possible prior to requesting it be enabled.

You can also refer to the link below for more information:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enabling-Create-Audit-Fields&language=en_US

Comment: This is changing the audit field on CREATE what about when the field is already created. Can it be UPDATED? Specifically the CreatedDate