# Is it possible to edit the Audit fields on UPDATE?

Tags: permissions, data-loader, system-fields, system-permissions, audit-fields

I found a question that was asked [7 years ago](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/17564/38191) but they are only mentioning that Audit fields can be change on Create/Insert...

What about when fields are already created and needs to update the Created Date of the Opportunity?

Re-creating fields in production for Opportunity records keeping the CreatedDate as date before doesn't seem like a plausible workaround..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Audit fields cannot be updated. While creation time these are created.
If already created Date cannot Be changed.
Re-creating fields in prodcution is not possible..